# ROS Answers SE migration: navigation

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all
can i use this code http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation on Pioneer 3dx /asectc peliecan
machine ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28917/navigation/) by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS navigation stack works on many different robots. I've seen it run on the Pioneer 3dx, but the Asectec Pelican is tougher because it involves 3D path-planning, and the navigation stack is 2D only.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2